# Weigth Paint on mirrored cubes

Tags: mirror-modifier

I created a mirrored object (lets say, left hand and right hand) and setup a bone for each one.

Now when I want to weight Paint on the left hand by select the bone on the left, I only able to paint on the original cube (right hand). And this will also mirror the paint, but I want to separate the weight paint for each one, is this possible or am supposed to not use the *Mirror* modifier?

To reproduce:
Open new File, select Cube, go to object modifiers and *Apply* the mirror. Now move the one cube in *Edit Mode* so you can see the two cubes.

Setup two bones and select the left bone and the cube, now try to weight paint on the left. You see nothing happen.

Comment: if you don't want to weight paint left hand and right hand exactly the same you need to apply the Mirror modifier

Comment: sorry i dont get it, where/on what do i have to apply the mirror modifier?

Comment: Could you please share your file with the 2 cubes as described at the end of your question?